# uiimage resize by scale factor

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

i am stuck in one problem i am creating image and it size is arounf 350*350 but i want to resize that image into small image like 32*32 or 16*16 i am doing that with this code

---

```
UIImage *scaledImage=img_Clip;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(16, 16),NO,0.0);
// Turn off interpolation to keep the scaled image from being blurred.
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);

[scaledImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 16)];  // scales image to rect
UIImage *resImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But i dont get the desired result my image become blurry i tried many thing but nothing work kindly help me

Comment: You are resizing something down to about 5% of what it was and cramming all that pixel data into a 16x16 icon. Of course it will become a little blurry.

Comment: to coneybeare's point, drastically reducing the size of a bitmapped image is going to be blurry because you're losing resolution.  If you are drawing the image yourself, you can probably get better results redrawing at the new size versus trying to scale down a larger image.

Comment: kindly provide me some code i am working for this from last 4 5 days but not get my desired result my current image is 350*350 and i want to make it 16*16

Comment: Do you use a UIImageView with your UIImage? That's another way of resizing but I don't know if it fits your needs. Let me know and I'll post some code.

Comment: ya i added image in uiimageview as well and thn take screenshot but no change still blurr image

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a `UIImageView` using your un-scaled `UIImage` and then change the frame.size of the image view. This will automatically scale down your image. Hopefully without making your image blurry.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView initWithImage:unscaledImage];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,16,16); // change the size of the image view
```

Give it a try.

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually it make blurry image but actually i want to copy that image in 16*16 and use that image as emoticon